# Como inserto un botón en un listado?

Tags: python-2.7, wxwidgets

Hola estoy realizando un listado y necesico agregar un boton de editar, he intentado muchas formas pero aun sin resultado...

```
self.index = 0
    self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(self.panel, pos=((50,70)), size=(610,100),
                     style=wx.LC_REPORT
                     |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN|wx.CENTRE
                     )

    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Nombre', width=100)
    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Apellido', width=100)
    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Direccion', width=100)
    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(3, 'Sexo', width=100)
    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(4, 'Cedula', width=100)
    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(5, 'Accion', width=100)
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM persona")
    resultados = cursor.fetchall() #muestra la fila

    images = ['img/v.jpg']

    self.il = wx.ImageList(50, 40)
    for i in images:
        self.il.Add(wx.Bitmap(i))


    for row in resultados:
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, row[0])
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, row[1])
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, row[2])
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 3, row[5])
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 4, str(row[7]))
        self.list_ctrl.SetImageList(self.il, wx.IMAGE_LIST_SMALL)
        self.list_ctrl.SetItemImage(self.index, 5)
        self.list_ctrl.Select(self.index)
        self.index += 1
```

en resumen solo necesito un botón en el listado que llame a una definición.. Gracias

Comment: Qué pasa cuando pruebas tu código y en qué difiere de lo que quieres como resultado?

Comment: Gracias por responder... cuando pruebo mi código aparece el listado con todos sus datos, (Nombre, Apellido, Dirección etc...) pero cuando trato de insertar un botón no puedo ... o mejor, No se como hacerlo... trate de insertar una imagen y lo hace pero una imagen no me sirve tiene que ser un boton para llamar a una definición ...